Disable msvsmon.exe(remote debugging) in vb.net 2017
I can run my application in vb.net 2017 with no issues when I run it on my own laptop.  The customer can run the application in debug mode with no issues while in Visual Studio 2017.  When my customer tries to run the vb_ex1.exe file on his company laptop, he gets an error from his network security software called "Parity".  The error is "Parity blocked an attempt by msvsmon.exe to run vb_ex1.exe because the file is not approved.  If you require access to this file, please contact your system administrator."  We had the system administrator allow the execution of vb_ex1.exe so the issue must be with msvsmon.exe.  From my research on Google it appears msvsmon.exe is responsible for remote debugging.  We don't even need to be able to use remote debugging. We are reluctant to ask the system administrator to allow msvsmon.exe because we are 99.99% sure they wont allow it.  Does anyone know how to disable remote debugging?  I was hoping it was a simple checkbox somewhere but I have had no luck finding a solution.
UPDATE 2024/07/19:
Forgot to mention that I created the application using Visual Studio Community 2019 and my customer is using Visual Studio 2017.
I updated the above description to make it clear that the customer is running the vb_ex1.exe file and not running in debug mode from Visual Studio.
Thanks, Chris
enter image description here
Tried deleting msvsmon.exe and adding  true line to vb_ex1.vbproj.user but both attempts to solve the problem didnt work.

Is there a particular reason why the customer is trying to run it from Visual Studio instead of running a release build of the program directly?

Did you build a Release build, create an installer for the application, and send the installer to the customer?

Thanks and Sorry, I was not clear in my original description.  I updated the above description to make it clear that the customer is running the vb_ex1.exe file and not running in debug mode from Visual Studio.  I did not build a Release build or installer.  I actually don't know how to do that.  I will educate myself on how to do that,

The following may be of interest: WIX Toolset, Publish ClickOnce applications, and .NET application publishing overview

You should now have enough information to resolve your issue.
